# PowerShell: $PSBoundParameters not available in Debug context

Tags: debugging, powershell, scripting

If I attempt to examine the PowerShell `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable during a PowerShell debugging session (eg. PowerShell ISE or Quest PowerGUI Script Editor), I cannot retrieve its value. However, if I simply allow the function to echo the `$PSBoundParameters` object to the pipeline, it renders as expected.

Does anyone know why this is? I would expect to be able to examine all in-scope variable during a debugging session, whether they are automatic, or user-defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to work for me if I assign it to a variable and look at the variable like this:

```
function Test-PSBoundParameters {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string] $Bar
    )

    $test = $PSBoundParameters
    $test | select *
}

Test-PSBoundParameters -Bar "a"
```

I couldn't inspect `$PSBoundParameters` while debugging but I could inspect `$test`. I'm not sure why this is, but at least you can use this as a work around.

Comment: Hmmmm that's a good work-around, but it still doesn't answer the core issue, which is why that variable is unavailable in the debugging context.

Answer (score 22):

Here's why, from [about_debuggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347652.aspx):

```
Displaying the Values of script Variables

While you are in the debugger, you can also enter commands, display the
value of variables, use cmdlets, and run scripts at the command line.

You can display the current value of all variables in the script that is
being debugged, except for the following automatic variables:

  $_
  $Args
  $Input
  $MyInvocation
  $PSBoundParameters

If you try to display the value of any of these variables, you get the
value of that variable for in an internal pipeline the debugger uses, not
the value of the variable in the script.

To display the value these variables for the script that is being debugged,
in the script, assign the value of the automatic variable to a new variable.
Then you can display the value of the new variable.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have more information concerning `$PSBoundParameters` in [about_Automatic_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347675.aspx). This variable has a value only in a scope where parameters are declared. So as far as PowerGui is concerned I can see the values of this var during debug as you can see hereunder.

[image]

You just see nothing inside `[DBG]` because there you are in an intereactive place due to a function with no arguments.

Comment: But then why is the $PSCmdlet variable available in debug context? It's the same situation as $PSBoundParameters ... it's an automatic variable that only exists in the function scope.

Comment: Just because [DBG] is obtained by the call of a function and not a Cmdlet so $PSCmdlet is not overwriten. Look in my example $PSCmdLet is $null.

Comment: I think in your example, $PSCmdlet is $null because you are not using the [CmdletBinding()] attribute on your function. Your function is what's known as a "v1" function, not a v2 advanced function.